# How to test a react component renders a list with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

I'm trying to understand how unit testing works and have built a small React app that renders out a list of Pokemon.
What I am trying to do is write a unit test that checks to see if the list is rendering properly. However, the snapshot that is generated shows that it only renders the 'loading ...' text which is what it is supposed to do while waiting for a response from the API.
What am I doing wrong?

**PokemonList.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PokemonList from '../components/PokemonList';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('PokemonList component renders a list of Pokemon', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const fetched = true;
        const loading = true;
        const species = [{
            "0": {"name": "bulbasaur"},
            "1": {"name": "ivysaur"},
            "2": {"name": "venusaur"}
        }];
        const rendered = renderer.create(
            <PokemonList fetched={fetched} loading={loading} species={species} />
        );
        expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

**PokemonList.js**

```
// The PokemonList component show nothing when it mounts for the first time.
// But right before it mounts to the DOM, it makes an API call to fetch the
// first 151 Pokemon for the API and then displays them using the Pokemon component.

import React from 'react';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';

class PokemonList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            species: [],
            fetched: false,
            loading: false,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
        fetch('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151').then(res=>res.json())
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({
                species: response.results,
                loading: true,
                fetched: true
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {fetched, loading, species} = this.state;
        let content ;
        if (fetched) {
            content = <div className="pokemon--species--list">{species.map((pokemon, index) => <Pokemon key={pokemon.name} id={index+1} pokemon={pokemon} />)}</div>
        } else if (loading && !fetched) {
            content = <p className="loading"> Loading ...</p>
        } else {
            content = <div/>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

**PokemonList.test.js.snap**

```
exports[`PokemonList component renders a list of Pokemon renders correctly 1`] = `
<div>
  <p
    className="loading">
     Loading ...
  </p>
</div>
`;
```

Comment: `loading` and `fetched` shouldn't both be true and the same time. Data is either being fetched `loading` or `fetched`

Comment: @dcodesmith I tried changing those values but I still get the same output in the snapshot

Comment: When you successfully fetch your data, your `loading` state should be `false` not `true` coz you're done fetching the data. Fix that and see what happens

Comment: @dcodesmith I've fixed that now and the app still works as expected but the test still outputs "loading ..." in the snapshot :(

Comment: Check the answer below. Hope that helps.

Comment: @dcodesmith what answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145697/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-john-thomson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change state in PokemonList component via props, but PokemonList don’t do anything with props, so the state doesn’t change. One way (and easiest in my opinion) to set the state and test your PokemonList component is with [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) and [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json). Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PokemonList from '../components/PokemonList';
// Importing shallow and toJson.
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import toJson from "enzyme-to-json";

describe('PokemonList component renders a list of Pokemon', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<PokemonList/>);
    const fetched = true;
    // You can omit setting the loading to true, because componentWillMount in PokemonList component takes care of that.
    //const loading = true;

    // I've changed your species array, that way it should work as expected.
    const species = [
      {name: "bulbasaur"},
      {name: "ivysaur"},
      {name: "venusaur"}
    ];

    wrapper.setState({
      fetched,
      species
    });

    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Also I would advise to use https in fetch.

Comment: @JohnThomson Happy to help!